# Updating and adding a specific value in a object in an array?

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to change a value in an object in an array,
So what i change is so random,  this is part of my code :

```js
const [data, setdata] = useState([
    { x: 1, y: 2 },
    { x: 1, y: 2 },
    { x: 1, y: 2 },
  ]);
```

I want to change whole X and also it can be added, like

the change data can be like this : `[3,4,5,6,7,8,9]`
and length can change.

So i tried to do it like this:

```js
 const updateX = () => {
    setdata(data => [...data.map(d => (d.x = [13, 21, 35, 3, 5, 6, 7]))]);
  };
```

but it gets error
I'd like to know how to solve it.
Thank you in advance

what I achieve is like this :

if I change it to [3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
then
`data` state should be like this :

```js
[3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

    { x: 3, y: 2 },
    { x: 4, y: 2 },
    { x: 5, y: 2 },
    { x: 6, y: 2 },
    { x: 7, y: 2 },
    { x: 8, y: 2 },
    { x: 9, y: 2 },
```

Comment: what is the expected result?

Comment: what i expect is just change `x` all the value and the length can be more than original value !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just update like this with `spread operator`

```
const updateX = () => {
  setdata((data) => data.map((d) => ({ ...d, x: [13, 21, 35, 3, 5, 6, 7] })));
};
```

Update:

```
const newData = [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

const updateX = () => {
  setdata((data) => data.map((d, i) => ({ ...d, x: newData[i] })));
};
```

Comment: Omg it's quiet easy ! Thank you so much Sir !!

Comment: I'm new here so I can't upvote your answer i will accept this answer later !  Thank you so much !

Comment: Sir I edited the question, would you mind if I ask about the achievement ??

Comment: Thank you so much ! However, data length can't change aha I will solve this problem .  So appreciate it !!